# how to build python with node-gyp?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, visual-studio, node-gyp

I've seen [the official tutorial](https://devguide.python.org/setup/) as well as [this](https://cpython-core-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_cpython_windows.html) one showing how to build python from source and edit it with visual studio etc., but how do I build it with node-gyp to use it as a native application in node?

For example, in the tutorial, they tell you to [download the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython), and then (in windows) type in that directory:

```
"PCbuild/build.bat"
```

and then that builds the Visual Studio solution and python in general etc., but now how do I do that with node-gyp? In general, to include external dependencies to build with node-gyp, you just include them in the binding.gyp file. For python, I first installed 64 bit (and later 32 bit, same error as below) [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) to C:/Python382, then I copied that folder to my another folder in my C++ application, and set the binding.gyp file to this (to get the include and libs):

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
        "target_name": "addon",
        "sources": [ 
            "<!@(node -p \"var fs=require('fs'),path=require('path'),walk=function(r){let t,e=[],n=null;try{t=fs.readdirSync(r)}catch(r){n=r.toString()}if(n)return n;var a=0;return function n(){var i=t[a++];if(!i)return e;let u=path.resolve(r,i);i=r+'/'+i;let c=fs.statSync(u);if(c&&c.isDirectory()){let r=walk(i);return e=e.concat(r),n()}return e.push(i),n()}()};walk('./sources').join(' ');\")"
        ],
        "libraries":[
            "C:/Users/Coby/Documents/aa/atzmus/CPPtesting/other/ok/Python382/libs/python38.lib",
            "C:/Users/Coby/Documents/aa/atzmus/CPPtesting/other/ok/Python382/libs/python3.lib",
            "C:/Users/Coby/Documents/aa/atzmus/CPPtesting/other/ok/Python382/libs/_tkinter.lib"
        ],
        "include_dirs": [
            "C:/Users/Coby/Documents/aa/atzmus/CPPtesting/other/ok/Python382/include"
        ],
        "dll_files": [
            "C:/Users/Coby/Documents/aa/atzmus/CPPtesting/other/ok/Python382/python38.dll"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my hello.cc file, which is the other source, simply includes `Python.h`. When I run this build using `node-gyp build` or `node-gyp rebuild`, it actually builds fine with no errors at all, but then when I copy over the file addon.node to my actual nodeJS server, which simply has the one line `var addon = require("./addon")`, I get the following error output in CMD (however, it works fine with no errors without including Python.h in my .cc source file):

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1197
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: \\?\C:\Users\Coby\Documents\aa\atzmus\testServer\addon.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\Coby\Documents\aa\atzmus\testServer\addon.node
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1197
:18)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Coby\Documents\aa\atzmus\testServer\oy.js:2:
9)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:1
0)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)←[39m
```

The main part seems to be:

> `addon.node is not a valid Win32 application.`

I tried doing this with python for 64bit windows, and for 32bit windows, my system in 64 bit, my nodeJS installation is 64 bit, but I also tried it with 32 bit note; I don't know how to fix this exactly, or if there is another way entirely to build python with node-gyp?

so:

**What steps need to be taken in windows to build  python through node-gyp, to be able to use python natively with nodejs without having to resort to child-process?**

Comment: what do you mean "to use python natively with nodejs"?

Comment: Python is not node.js addon

Comment: @NizamMohamed who said it was? Its a C++ application. Node-gyp allows the use of C++ applications within nodejs. The question is simply how to compile it and use its C++ functions within nodeJS, using node-gyp

Comment: Recently I had to add a global package of node-gyp for some things to work again.

Comment: @Jacob what do u mean? I tried to install by npm -i -g node-gyp

Comment: Once I had installed it globally I stopped getting the similar node-gyp errors :/ if that didn't do it for you then I am out of ideas personally. Sorry

Comment: @Jacob what code did you use exactly? And what device do you have -- windows 64 or 32? And what version of python, as well as what bit-version of python, 32 or 64?

Comment: My issue had to do with node-sass which uses node-gyp for something. I have a MacBook pro

Comment: @bluejayke I dont know if you found an answer but I found more resources no node-gyp issues maybe this will help https://github.com/schnerd/d3-scale-cluster/issues/7#issuecomment-402541605

Comment: I think this is what I ended up doing back then to fix it, but did a more permanent fix after the last Catalina MacOS update https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md#i-did-all-that-and-the-acid-test-still-does-not-pass--